# How do I separate a list at specific points?

Tags: python

I have:

```
Z = [2, 3, 2]
M = [2, 6, 3, 1, 5, 8, 3]
```

And I would like to separate the list `M` according to `Z` list like:

```
l = [[2, 6], [3, 1, 5], [8, 3]]
```

I tried:

```
z = 0
l = list()
for i, z in enumerate(M):
    if z == Z[0]:
        l.append(M[z:i+1])
        z = i+1
        del Z[0]
    z = z+1
```

But then I obtained an empty list `l=[]`

Comment: Use the code formatting option to make your code readable. Also, because this is Python, it will handily preserve whitespace.

Comment: You use `z` as variable name twice, don't do that. Bad practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following (assuming I understand you problem correctly):

```
M = [2, 6, 3, 1, 5, 8, 3]
Z = [2, 3, 2]
l=[]

for z in Z:
    l.append(M[0:z])
    del M[0:z]
```

which gives you the desired output:

```
[[2, 6], [3, 1, 5], [8, 3]]
```

So you basically just loop through `Z`, append the first `z` elements of `Z` to your list `l` and delete these afterwards from your list `M`.

Comment: Thank you!! I was complicating the problem. I don't have much experience.

Comment: Glad I could help! And also thanks for accepting the answer! Enjoy stackoverflow and keep hacking :)

Answer (score 0):

This should be easier with slicing of lists, the following code does the job:

```
idx = 0
l = []
for z in Z:
    l.append(M[idx:idx+z])
    idx += z
```

Here `idx` keeps track of the number of elements already processed. For this to work nicely, we require `sum(Z) == len(M)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
M = [2, 6, 3, 1, 5, 8, 3]
Z = [2, 3, 2]

[M[x[1]-x[0]:x[1]] for x in zip(Z,itertools.accumulate(Z))]
```

output:

```
[[2, 6], [3, 1, 5], [8, 3]]
```